# How pipeline multiple maps in Java 8

Tags: dictionary, merge, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I want to merge a large number of text files, each containing ~1000 characters. During the merging, I want to replace a couple of sequences with their pairs. I am not super familiar with the functional feature released in Java8, so the first solution for me is to map a sequence to its substitution with a map function, i.e.

```
Arrays.asList(String[]).stream().
                map( s -> s.replaceAll("_A_", " and ") ).
                map( s -> s.replaceAll("_O_", " or ") ).
                map( s -> s.replaceAll("_X_", " xor ") ).
                reduce( (a,b) -> a + b );
```

Obviously, this code snippet is not easily extendable if one wants to add/remove a subtiution particularly during runtime. One solution crossed my mind is to store all the sequences in a map, like `replacingMap`, and iterate over it to replace all sequences.

```
final Map<String, String> replacingMap = new HashMap();
replacingMap.put("_A_"," and ");
replacingMap.put("_O_"," or ");
replacingMap.put("_x_"," xor ");
```

Now the original code can be rewritten as below where `f` takes `s` as a string. Based on the given map it replaces all the sequences and returns the substituted string.

```
Arrays.asList(String[]).stream().
                map( s -> f(s) ).
                reduce( (a,b) -> a + b );
```

My implementation for `f` is in imperative style where all the sequences are being replaced in a basic `for` loop.

My question is how `f` can be written in a fully functional style without using imperative loops?

Answer (score 5):

What you probably want is to *compose* the different string mapping functions into a single function that you can then pass to a `map()` operation. The functions that end up getting composed can be determined at runtime using program logic, data in data structures, etc.

Before we dive in, a few unrelated tips that I'll use in my examples:

- Don't use `reduce((a, b) -> a + b)` to concatenate strings, since it has O(n^2) complexity. Use `collect(Collectors.joining())` instead.
- If you're starting with an array of strings, you can use `Arrays.stream()` to stream them without wrapping them in a `List` first.
- If you're reading the lines from a file, you can use `BufferedReader.lines()` to get a stream of lines without having to load them into a data structure first. (Not shown in my examples.)

First let's show function composition by starting off with a list of functions to be composed.

```
    List<Function<String,String>> replList = new ArrayList<>();
    replList.add(s -> s.replaceAll("_A_", " and "));
    replList.add(s -> s.replaceAll("_O_", " or "));
    replList.add(s -> s.replaceAll("_X_", " xor "));
```

We want to *reduce* this list of an arbitrary number of functions down to one function, by streaming the list and reducing over `Function.compose()`. What `compose` does is to take two functions *f* and *g* and creates a new function that calls *g*, and then calls *f* with the result of having called *g*. This might seem like it's backwards, but it makes sense mathematically. If you have *y = f(g(x))* then *g* is applied first. (There is also another function `Function.andThen` which applies the functions in the opposite order.)

Here's what the code to do this looks like:

```
    Function<String,String> mapper = replList.stream()
        .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::compose);
```

Now `func` is a composite function that calls all the functions that were in `replList`. We can now use this as the argument to a single `map()` operation in a stream pipeline:

```
    System.out.println(
        Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(mapper)
            .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

(Note that I'm using `Function<String,String>` in the above instead of the arguably equivalent `UnaryOperator<String>`. The problem is that there is no `compose` method that returns a `UnaryOperator`, so we have to stick with the `Function` type instead.)

This works if you happen to have the functions you want to apply already written. If you want to do replacements based on data that's loaded from somewhere, then using a `Map` for this is a reasonable idea. How would we do that?

You could run through the map and generate a function from each key-value pair, collect them into a list, and reduce that list as shown above. But it's not necessary to have the intermediate list, as it's possible to do the reduction over a stream of map entries. Let's start from your example:

```
    Map<String,String> replMap = new HashMap<>();
    replMap.put("_A_", " and ");
    replMap.put("_O_", " or ");
    replMap.put("_X_", " xor ");
```

We want to stream over the map entries, but we want to reduce to a single function. That's different from the case above, where we had many functions of the same type and we wanted to reduce them to a single function of the same type. In this case, we want the input type to be map entries but the result type to be a function. How do we do that?

We need to use the three-arg overload of `reduce`, which takes an *identity*, an *accumulator*, and a *combiner*. Our identity function is, as before, `Function.identity()`. The combiner is also easy, since we already know how to compose two functions using `Function.compose()`.

The tricky one is the accumulator function. At each call, takes a value of the input type and applies it to an intermediate result, and returns the result of that application. What makes this trickier is that the result type is itself a function. So our accumulator needs to take a function, accumulate something into (onto?) it, and return another function.

Here's a lambda expression that does that:

```
    (func, entry) ->
        func.compose(s -> s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
```

The types are all going to be inferred, so they're not declared, but the type of `func` is `Function<String,String>` and the type of `entry` is `Map.Entry<String,String>` which shouldn't be too surprising given the problem we're working on.

And here's what that looks like in a stream:

```
    Function<String,String> mapper = replMap.entrySet().stream()
        .reduce(Function.identity(),
                (func, entry) ->
                    func.compose(s -> s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())),
                Function::compose);
```

Now we can use the resulting `mapper` function in a stream over the input data just like we did above.

It's unlikely to be an issue, I think, but one point about the above is that the composite function captures every map entry and gets the key and value out of each entry, each time it processes an input element. If this bothers you (it bothers me, a little bit) you can write a slightly bigger lambda that extracts the data before capturing them in the lambda that's returned:

```
    (func, entry) -> {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        return func.compose(s -> s.replaceAll(key, value));
     },
```

This function itself is a bit clearer, I think, but using multi-line lambdas tends to clutter up stream pipelines.

In any case, let's put it all together. Given the input:

```
String[] input = {
    "[", "_A_", "_O_", "_X_", "_O_", "_M_", "_O_", "_X_", "_O_", "_A_", "]"
};
```

and the set of replacement strings in a map:

```
    Map<String,String> replMap = new HashMap<>();
    replMap.put("_A_", " and ");
    replMap.put("_O_", " or ");
    replMap.put("_X_", " xor ");
```

we generate a combined mapping function:

```
    Function<String,String> mapper = replMap.entrySet().stream()
        .reduce(Function.identity(),
                (func, entry) -> {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    return func.compose(s -> s.replaceAll(key, value));
                },
                Function::compose);
```

and then use it to process the input:

```
    System.out.println(
        Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(mapper)
            .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Finally, the result is:

```
[ and  or  xor  or _M_ or  xor  or  and ]
```

**UPDATE 2015-02-05**

Based on some suggestions from Marko Topolnik and from Holger, here's a simplified version of the mapper:

```
    Function<String,String> mapper = replMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> (Function<String,String>) s -> s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .reduce(Function::compose)
        .orElse(Function.identity());
```

This has two simplifications. First, a mapping from the `MapEntry` to a `Function` is done prior to the reduction step, so we can use the simpler form of `reduce`. Note that I had to put an explicit cast to `Function<String,String>` into this mapping step, since I couldn't get type inference to work. (This was on JDK 8u25.) Second, instead of using `Function.identity()` as the identity value of the two-arg `reduce` operation, we can use the one-arg form, which returns an `Optional`, and then substitute `Function.identity()` if the value isn't present in the resulting `Optional`. Neat!

Comment: +1 for a great and detailed answer; however I found one thing that will trap the reader: in the first example `compose` is used as the *accumulator*, but this is not mentioned explicitly; then in the second example, the same function is used as the *combiner* while introducing another accumulator. The two-arg `reduce` actually reuses the accumulator as combiner so both examples use `compose` as the combiner. All this is quite confusing and would need more explicit explanation.

Comment: Also, looking at this: `replMap.entrySet().stream().reduce(Function.identity() (func, entry) -> func.compose(s -> s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())), Function::compose);` I would say that what you really do here is map an entry to a function, then reduce with `compose`. With this in mind it could be simplified: `replMap.entrySet().stream().map(e -> s -> s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())).reduce(identity(), Function::compose);` This way the analogy to the first example stands out much more clearly (a mapping step is introduced which resolves the "impedance mismatch").

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Right, and I would prefer `reduce(Function::compose).orElse(identity())` to avoid composing a function with an identity function…

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the suggestion. I do think that extracting the mapping from the reduction simplifies things. I couldn't get the type inference to work, so I had to put in a cast, but it's still an improvement. Though it's somewhat moot at this point, I'm not sure whether it's worthwhile to make an issue of *accumulator* vs *combiner* in the different forms of `reduce`. In particular, note that the accumulator of the one- and two-arg forms is a different type than the accumulator of the three-arg form, but it's the same time as the three-arg combiner.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your suggestion as well. I've updated the answer with both yours and Marko's suggestions. And congratulations for getting the first java-8 gold tag badge!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I'll say this in the interest of future readers: a type witness is usually preferred to a cast: `...stream().<Function<String,String>>map(...`

Comment: @Stuart Marks: thanks, maybe I’ll print it on a real badge ;^)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In this case I think the cast is clearer. We have a lambda that returns a lambda, in the form `map(e -> s -> s.foo())`. If we have to help the compiler with its types, putting the cast in, e.g. `map(e -> (Type) s -> s.foo())` makes clear the type of what's being returned. With `<Type>map(e -> s -> s.foo())` it's not self-evident what `Type` means in this context, and you have to look at the definition of `map` to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a regex to split your strings and then replace all matches using `Map.getOrDefault`. However, the following examples assume that all matching entries are based on the same pattern (`_` before and after the letter).

```
// Replacement data
final Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("_A_", " and ");
m.put("_O_", " or ");
m.put("_X_", " xor ");

// This version keeps the lines as an array. It creates an inner
// stream for each line and in the end all is mapped to a new String[]
final String[] multipleLines = Arrays.stream(lines)
        .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("((?<=_.?_)|(?=_.?_))"))
                .map(word -> m.getOrDefault(word, word))
                .collect(Collectors.joining()))
        .toArray(String[]::new);

// This version simply joins all strings to one big String.
// The flatMap-method combines a series of Streams to one Stream
final String oneLongString = Arrays.stream(lines)
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("((?<=_.?_)|(?=_.?_))")))
        .map(word -> m.getOrDefault(word, word))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```